When standardizing music from my audio library, what should my workflow look like?
I am a complete beginner when it comes to audio engineering but I would like to create a workflow in Audacity to 'standardize' some of my personal piano recordings. My main problem is that many of them vary in their average and peak loudness. In addition, I sometimes encounter background noise that I need to remove. Finally, I have no reference values for certain constants, like how long the silence before and after a track should be.
So far, I have come up with the following workflow:

When the track contains outlier peaks, I use compression to reduce them (not sure how).
I use either the 'normalize' or 'loudness normalization' function to make the track consistent with other tracks.
I apply 'noise reduction' to the whole track if necessary.
I use the 'truncate silence' function to adjust the start and the end lengths.

Is there a guide online that could help me with my specific use case? Is anything missing from these steps?

The question is what planned use you have for the recordings?
Regardless, avoid damaging modifications. So I would suggest the following:

Remove recordings and parts of recordings that you will never use.
Normalize each recording individually to -2dB FS (keep a bit headroom)
Have 1 second of room tone in beginning and end of each recording.

Don´t compress, don´t remove noise as both will damage the recordings and in a few years time you will have better tools will know better how to use them.
--- added after question from OP
Sorry, your question was not clear to me. Save non-destructive versions of your recordings should remain. Work on copies. Some ideas:

Remove the really low frequencies. They seldom add any music content (exception, some organ recordings) and will not be reproduced by most speakers. Use highpass filter. Your taste may vary, but I suggest 60Hz, 24dB.
First step of normalizing is for -2dB (normalize, not loudness normalizing).
I tend to have 1 second before music and 1.5 seconds after music. You do whatever feels best for you. The remove silence plugin can be helpful, but sometimes makes a mess instead. Try -30dB, 1 second.
Maybe remove noise. I personally don't like the plugin and never use it, so do whatever works for you.
Reduce dynamic range by compressor. Here you need to try what settings work for you. Maybe Podcast/Radio preset? Note that compression in a way is introducing distortion and can be both a blessing and very annoying.
Second pass of normalizing. You may try loudness normalizing to get all recordings at same level if you like it.
Always finish by running the limiter. Modern preset might work for you.
Export as mp3 if you like that.
Redo the process from unprocessed saved files when your taste has changed and you might have access to better tools or want to adapt to different listening environments.


Hi @ghellquist ! I just like the way I play certain pieces on the piano and I want to listen to my own recordings. A few questions about your answer: How did you come to the -2dB FS? Is that some sort of standard? Also, which function did you use - 'normalize' or 'loudness normalization'? Finally, what should be the threshold be for the 'truncate silence' function?
